# Javascript alert only in ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, alert, browser-detection

I want an alert box only in Internet Explorer in java script... How can I write in .js file.

```
<!--[if IE 8]><!-->
alert("only in IE8");
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I use this code previously but it doesn't work.. is there any need to add js file for execute this or any code for this.

```
if (isIE8) {
    alert('Your browser is IE8');
}
```

If I use this code javascript stops the execution in chrome and firefox.

Comment: yes i use jquery code

Answer (score 1):

A good approach for this issue would be rendering `html` tag with different class name for IE8.

Something like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //with jQuery
        (function(){
            if($('html').is('.ie8')) {
                alert('This is IE8');
            }
        });



        //with JavaScript
        function ElementHasClass(elem, class) {
            return (' ' + elem.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + class + ' ') > -1;
        }
        var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
        if (ElementHasClass(htmlElement, "ie8")){
            alert('This is IE8');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Your can also use class `ie8` in your CSS in case you need a special style

Comment: Just to point out 'class' is [a keyword as of ES6](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-keywords), so you might want to change it to cls or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response.. I use another code for that alert..

```
  if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8.")!=-1)
  {
  alert("File Deleted Successfully");
  }
```

This is for IE8. It works

Answer (score 0):

i got answer of alert please try it working perfectly as your want .

```
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]--> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
  if(IE10orBelow() < 9) {
    alert('Update Your ie explorer or use other brower!');
  }
  function IE10orBelow() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0) {
      // IE 10 or older => return version number
      return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
  }
  }
  </script>
```